# Express module install issue

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install express. I have typed npm install -g express through cmd, which runs, but when I try to use a express command such ass: 
Express newapp 
It says, express is not installed.

If anyone knows as to why express is not installing please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: @RichardKho How do I do that Richard?

Answer (score 0):

You want to install `express-generator` globally to use express in your bash.

Comment: Okay so 'npm install -g express-generator'?

Comment: yes. You installed the express framework globally, but this isn't the generator you probably wanted. Feel free to accept this answer :)

Comment: I am still getting nothing when I run express

Comment: Then either you are using the wrong bash or I don't know or I interpreted your problem wrongly.

Comment: @cluch And no, you didn't interpret it incorrectly.

Comment: Then you need to explain your problem in a different way. Nobody seems to understand your question.